# Add some text around email addresses in multiple files

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I have a number of text files in a folder. The text in them is in this format:

```
%%%%%%%%%%@yahoo.com
%%%%%%@wanadoo.fr
%%%%raviplywoodglasscentre@yahoo.comravi
%%nameemail%%@yahoo.com
%.getincontact@numberland.com
%0dronbracale@roadrunner.com
%1%3@example.com
%1@elsewhere.com
%1@example.com
```

I want to make changes in all the files text and make them like the following:

```
{"email":"%%%%%%%%%%@yahoo.com"}
{"email":"%%%%%%@wanadoo.fr"}
{"email":"%%%%raviplywoodglasscentre@yahoo.comravi"}
{"email":"%%nameemail%%@yahoo.com"}
```

I want to make the complete files like this which are in a folder.
I have tried this:

```
awk '{ printf("{"email":"%s"}", $l);}' test
```

but it didn't work.

So, is there any way that I can modify the text in all the files in a folder like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/.*/{"email":"&"}/' file
{"email":"%%%%%%%%%%@yahoo.com"}
{"email":"%%%%%%@wanadoo.fr"}
{"email":"%%%%raviplywoodglasscentre@yahoo.comravi"}
{"email":"%%nameemail%%@yahoo.com"}
{"email":"%.getincontact@numberland.com"}
{"email":"%0dronbracale@roadrunner.com"}
{"email":"%1%3@example.com"}
{"email":"%1@elsewhere.com"}
{"email":"%1@example.com"}
```

So to act on all files you could do

```
sed -i 's/.*/{"email":"&"}/' *
```

To keep a copy of the old files

```
sed -i.old 's/.*/{"email":"&"}/' *
```

#### Explanation

- `-i.old` modify files in place instead of printing to stdout, and save a copy of each file before modification with an extension `.old`
- `s/old/new` replace `old` with `new`
- `.*` any characters on the line
- `&` the matched pattern

Comment: Will it work if I replace `file` with the `folder` path?

Comment: @JafferWilson my answer assumes you are running commands inside the directory. If that is not the case, replace `file` with the actual `/path/to/file` and `*` with the actual `/path/to/directory/*`

Comment: We both slightly misread the desired output (missing second ", before : ).

Answer (score 5):

No doubt more verbose, but to edit all files inside a directory:

1. If the directory is flat:

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import os
   import sys

   dr = sys.argv[1]

   for file in [os.path.join(dr, f) for f in os.listdir(dr)]:
       newtext = "\n".join(['{"email":"'+l.strip()+'"}'for l in open(file).readlines()])
       open(file, "wt").write(newtext)
   ```
2. If the directory is recursive, and you need to convert files in subdirs as well:

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import os
   import sys

   dr = sys.argv[1]

   for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dr):
       for file in files:
           file = os.path.join(root, file)
           newtext = "\n".join(['{"email":"'+l.strip()+'"}'for l in open(file).readlines()])
           open(file, "wt").write(newtext)
   ```

In both cases, the file's content changes into:

```
{"email":"%%%%%%%%%%@yahoo.com"}
{"email":"%%%%%%@wanadoo.fr"}
{"email":"%%%%raviplywoodglasscentre@yahoo.comravi"}
{"email":"%%nameemail%%@yahoo.com"}
{"email":"%.getincontact@numberland.com"}
{"email":"%0dronbracale@roadrunner.com"}
{"email":"%1%3@example.com"}
{"email":"%1@elsewhere.com"}
{"email":"%1@example.com"}
```

#### To use it

1. Copy the script (either one) into an empty file, save it as `edit_files.py`
2. Run it with the directory as argument:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/edit_files.py /path/to/files_to_convert
   ```

#### Note

This assumes *all lines* inside *all files* need to be edited. Please mention if we need to set a condition for either one, or both.

Comment: Since you're using Python already, you should use a proper JSON serialization, that will take care of escaping quotes correctly

Comment: @Kroltan agreed, but OP's desired output doesn't align with json format , simply because json file is a single dictionary, so to speak. OP has multiple dictionaries in single file

Comment: @Serg Multiple JSON documents in a file is actually a entirely common usage, given that whitespace is irrelevant, and non-pretty-printed JSON always fits in a line.

Comment: @Kroltan that's nice to know ! I might whip out something with json API when I have time. I've used it before, but never with multiple json documents in same file

Comment: @Kroltan posted a solution

Answer (score 4):

With `awk`, use variable assignment to remove one level of quoting:

```
awk -v format='{"email":"%s"}\n' '{printf format, $1}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the stream editor `sed` for this:

```
sed -e 's/\(^.*\)$/{"email":"\1"}/g' source.txt
```

Comment: But it is not taking folder as input. `sed` take only file name as input here. I do not want to give one by one filename.

Comment: @JafferWilson you can use a shell glob to catch all the files, but you will see the edited contents of all the files printed to stdout and they will not be modified - to actually change all the files, add the `-i` flag

Comment: @Zanna Thank you for you advice. I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

Perl way:

```
$ perl -lane 'print "{\"email\":\"$_\"}"' input.txt                                                                      
{"email":"%%%%%%%%%%@yahoo.com"}
{"email":"%%%%%%@wanadoo.fr"}
{"email":"%%%%raviplywoodglasscentre@yahoo.comravi"}
{"email":"%%nameemail%%@yahoo.com"}
```

This can be used on multiple files in a folder as so:

```
for file in * ; do perl -lane 'print "{\"email\":\"$_\"}"' "$file" > "$file".json ; done
```

---

Python and json API:

```
$ ls
input2.txt  input.txt  json_encode.py*                                                                                                                
$ ./json_encode.py * 
$ ls
input2.txt  input2.txt.json  input.txt  input.txt.json  json_encode.py*  json_encode.py.json
$ cat input.txt.json
{"email": "%%%%%%%%%%@yahoo.com"}
{"email": "%%%%%%@wanadoo.fr"}
{"email": "%%%%raviplywoodglasscentre@yahoo.comravi"}
{"email": "%%nameemail%%@yahoo.com"}
```

And here's the script itself:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import sys

for file in sys.argv[1:]:
     if __file__ in file or '.json' in file: continue
     with open(file,'r') as fd1:
         for line in fd1:
             data = { "email": line.strip() }
             with open(file+ ".json","a") as fd2:
                  json.dump(data,fd2)
                  fd2.write("\n")
```