# How I can I group emails by domain, combined and summarized from all files in a directory?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have some CSV files. Each file has a list of email addresses. The following is extracted data from the file:

```
%%%%%%%%%%@yahoo.com
%%%%%%@wanadoo.fr
%%%%raviplywoodglasscentre@yahoo.comravi
%%nameemail%%@yahoo.com
%.getincontact@numberland.com
%1%3@example.com
%1@example.com
```

What I am trying to attempt is extracting domains from these email address and then arranging the email addresses in such a manner that the emails associated with a certain domain are listed together.
For example:

```
yahoo.com,%%%%%%%%%%@yahoo.com
wanadoo.fr,%%%%%%@wanadoo.fr
yahoo.comravi,%%%%raviplywoodglasscentre@yahoo.comravi
yahoo.com,%%nameemail%%@yahoo.com
numberland.com,%.getincontact@numberland.com
example.com,%1%3@example.com
example.com,%1@example.com
```

The final output I am trying to acquire is like the following:

```
yahoo.com,%%%%%%%%%%@yahoo.com,%%nameemail%%@yahoo.com
wanadoo.fr,%%%%%%@wanadoo.fr
yahoo.comravi,%%%%raviplywoodglasscentre@yahoo.comravi
numberland.com,%.getincontact@numberland.com
example.com,%1%3@example.com,%1@example.com
```

Comment: This is almost the same question as you [asked yesterday](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875606/add-some-text-around-email-addresses-in-multiple-files), only the regular expression will differ. You should consider taking a while to learn how to use them.

Comment: @Melebius Please read the question my friend. It is not exact same.

Comment: looks completely different to me...

Comment: @Zanna Yes it is different. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: ...Totally, I don't see how this can be the same.

Comment: @JafferWilson I wrote _almost_ same, it’s just another instance of text transforming questions. (If it was exact same, I would mark it duplicate.) I tried to express you should learn to fish instead of asking for a fish. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime

Comment: Hi @JafferWilson just curious, but did you try the latest version?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Well, I was busy with some other process. I will try it now. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A python way, using `itertools`' `groupby()`:

#### 1. Write output per file (of all files in a directory) in the terminal

*N.B. Mind that the terminal shows a limited number of lines*

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby
import os
import sys

dr = sys.argv[1]

for f in os.listdir(dr):
    lines = [[l.strip(), l.split("@")[-1].strip()] for l in \
             open(os.path.join(dr, f)).readlines()]
    lines.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
    for item, occurrence in groupby(lines, itemgetter(1)):
        func = [s[0] for s in list(occurrence)]; print(item+","+",".join(func))
```

#### To use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `group_domains.py`
2. Run it with the targeted directory as argument:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/group_domains.py /directory/with/files
   ```

Output will be like:

```
example.com,%1%3@example.com,%1@example.com
numberland.com,%.getincontact@numberland.com
wanadoo.fr,%%%%%%@wanadoo.fr
yahoo.com,%%%%%%%%%%@yahoo.com,%%nameemail%%@yahoo.com
yahoo.comravi,%%%%raviplywoodglasscentre@yahoo.comravi
```

#### Notes

As it is, the script creates an output *per file* in the terminal. We could easily combine (summarize) the output(s) of the separate files, and subsequently write the grouped result into a file etc., but please mention.

#### Explanation

In the concept:

1. The file's lines are read, and split by "@" to read the domain
2. The created list is subsequently *sorted* by domain:

   ```
   lines.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
   ```
3. and grouped by domain:

   ```
   groupby(lines, itemgetter(1))
   ```

The outcome (line) is made of the item (domain) and its "members".

#### 2. Write report per file (again of all files in a directory) into renamed files.

The script below will write the output into a renamed file, usage is the same:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby
import os
import sys

dr = sys.argv[1]


for f in os.listdir(dr):
    write = []
    file = os.path.join(dr, f)
    lines = [[l.strip(), l.split("@")[-1].strip()] for l in open(file).readlines()]
    lines.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
    for item, occurrence in groupby(lines, itemgetter(1)):
        func = [s[0] for s in list(occurrence)]
        write.append(item+","+",".join(func))
    open(os.path.join(dr, "grouped_"+f), "wt").write("\n".join(write))
```

from a file like:

```
some_list.txt
```

it will create a renamed one:

```
grouped_some_list.txt
```

#### To use

simply:

```
python3 /path/to/group_domains.py /directory/with/files
```

#### 3. Write a report (summary) on the whole directory into a single file

The version below will summarize all domains inside the files in a directory. The report is saved in a file, to set as second argument.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby, chain
import os
import sys

dr = sys.argv[1]
outfile = sys.argv[2]

report = []

for f in os.listdir(dr):
    lines = [[l.strip(), l.split("@")[-1].strip()] for l in \
             open(os.path.join(dr, f)).readlines()]
    lines.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
    for item, occurrence in groupby(lines, itemgetter(1)):
        func = [s[0] for s in list(occurrence)]
        report.append([item, func])

report.sort(key=itemgetter(0))

with open(outfile, "wt") as out:
    for item, occurrence in groupby(report, itemgetter(0)):
        func = [item for sublist in [it[1] for it in list(occurrence)] for item in sublist]
        out.write(item+","+",".join(func)+"\n")
```

#### To use

1. Copy the script into an emty file
2. Run it:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/group_domains.py /directory/with/files /path/to/outputfile.txt
   ```

   (or whatever extension)

#### Notes

The last version will first summarize *per file*, as mentioned in the question, and ***additionally*** summarize all files into an output file, where similar domains from the separate files will be combined into one line per domain.

Comment: Will it take longer time. Is it possible to make it faster? Well, this is a great answer, but let me check it out.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52440/discussion-between-jaffer-wilson-and-jacob-vlijm lets chat.

Comment: @JafferWilson summarizing version added, as discussed in chat.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a `perl` version, using a hash of anonymous arrays:

```
$ perl -F@ -alne '
    push @{ $h{$F[1]} }, $_ }{ 
    for $k (reverse sort keys %h) {print join ",", $k, @{ $h{$k} }
  }' emails.csv
yahoo.comravi,%%%%raviplywoodglasscentre@yahoo.comravi
yahoo.com,%%%%%%%%%%@yahoo.com,%%nameemail%%@yahoo.com
wanadoo.fr,%%%%%%@wanadoo.fr
numberland.com,%.getincontact@numberland.com
example.com,%1%3@example.com,%1@example.com
```

The order isn't *exactly* what you asked for

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is it possible to give a complete folder instead of one single file

Comment: @JafferWilson you really should start trying these things yourself. You seem to be treating this site as a free script writing service. Surely between the several answers you've received so far, you must be starting to learn how to write your own. At the very least, you can search google for "iterate over files in directory" or something.

Comment: @JafferWilson the perl one-liner implicitly will read and iterate over multiple files on the command line, so unless the list of files exceeds the shell's `ARG_MAX` you shouldn't need to do anything more than a shell glob of files in the directory. Otherwise, you will need to modify it to loop over the directory contents internally - see for example [Open and read from files](https://perlmaven.com/open-and-read-from-files)

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{a[$1] = a[$1]","$2} END {for (i in a) print i a[i]}'
```

The output isn't in any particular order:

```
$ awk -F, '{a[$1] = a[$1]","$2} END {for (i in a) print i a[i]}' foo
yahoo.comravi,%%%%raviplywoodglasscentre@yahoo.comravi
yahoo.com,%%%%%%%%%%@yahoo.com,%%nameemail%%@yahoo.com
numberland.com,%.getincontact@numberland.com
example.com,%1%3@example.com,%1@example.com
wanadoo.fr,%%%%%%@wanadoo.fr
```

Comment: This is not given expected output. Something different then the answer. But attempt is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: @JafferWilson Oh? Except for the order, I get the same output as, say, steeldriver's answer http://askubuntu.com/a/875979/158442